# What is the best way to have once sentence live on two lines with responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

For design purposes I want to have one sentence split over to another line, the issue I am having is seamlessly having it fit within the containing div as the resolution gets smaller. The way I currently have it set up is by setting the width of the sentence to be smaller than the containing div so that any text after the word "all" moves down to the next line. The issue I am running into is obviously the % width doesn't look good on any media query lower than the highest resolution.

Is the only way to do this is by creating multiple media queries?

Current Code:

```css
div.slide {
  padding: 110px 30px 110px 30px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.slide-content {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
div.slide-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="slide-content">
    <div class="slide-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cLorem ipsum dolor sit amet onsectetuer adipiscing elit-all Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow has its own HTML/CSS/JavaScript snippet function which is preferred over JSFiddle. It's the icon which looks like a sheet of paper with angled brackets, or you can press CTRL + M. I've done it for you this time but please use this feature in future!

Comment: @Michael, I appreciate the feedback! I will be sure to use Stackoverflow's snippet function in the future.

Comment: No worries. I'm having a little trouble figuring out exactly what you're asking for. Should the text always fall precisely on two lines (no more, no less)? Is it reasonable to change the font size?

Comment: Hello Michael, what I am trying to do is always keep any text after "adipiscing elit-all" always be on the line below the text. It is alright to change the size, so long as it can be read on mobile. I know I can do this by creating multiple media queries, but I am just not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest using media queries for this.
If you want to completely take over where does sentence break you can add line break tag at exact place but I wouldn't recommend doing so as it might affect other resolutions as well.

So .slide-text width in combination with media queries should be just fine :)

e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  div.slide-text {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  div.slide-text {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 901px) {
  div.slide-text {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

Just make sure you update it to suit your needs :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this is what I was thinking too. I guess I was hoping that something has developed in css where you wouldn't have to set the width, but as long as I set the media queries properly, it can still look refined as opposed to sloppy. Thanks again!

Comment: Well you can try this - add <br> tag into your content and check until which window size does it look nice and at that point include media query with something like this `@media (max-width: 900px) {
  div.slide-text br {
    display:none;
  }
}` This will hide line break on lower then 900px but you'll still have it on higher resolutions :)

Comment: You could also assign class to the <br class="randomClass"> and place br's on different places if you want and using css hide the ones you want to hide on certain screen sizes :)

Comment: Interesting technique, I will try this out.  I appreciate the suggestions!